# Is there an error/status log for java? My program just stops running without any output

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to benchmark execution time for a program I created.  As I add more data for it to process it takes longer and I am trying to find out how long exactly and a few details about the program(number of loops, time for each loop,etc..) so I created a `system.out.println`... of the status messages I want.  This program works with a small number of variables quickly, but to run it on a large amount I do: `java my_program > results.txt &`

I see the job running for about 2 hours than it vanishes, so assuming its finished I try to cat results.txt but its blank.  If java was crashing, wouldn't the error message be in there also(I think I'm capturing all output)?  If not, is there a place I can find this information?

Comment: Have you checked your program really outputs something (with a small number of variables)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redirected stdout to a file, but any errors would have been written to strderr, which was not redirected. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html for an example of how to redirect both stdout and stderr

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
java my_program 1>results.txt 2>error_log.txt &
```

This would actually redirect your errors to error_log.txt and your sysouts to results.txt